# Need help to write SQL Pivot query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

This is my User table schema and I need the following result set. I am using MS SQL server.

[image]

I have tried with SQL server Pivot but it will show wrong result.

My Pivot Query

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [ID],[Email],[DepartmentName]
      FROM [dbo].[User]) U
      PIVOT (
      COUNT([DepartmentName]) 
      FOR [DepartmentName] IN( [D1],[D2],[D3],[D4])
  ) AS pivot_table;
```

Above query will show the following result.

[image]

It shows multiple email address row. I need only one user row.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't use images to supply data. Post data as text, either as tabular formatted `text`, or (even better) as DDL and DML statements. Then we have a [mre] and can easily tell you what's wrong with your attempt.

Comment: Sure @Larnu I will use   text    in my next question. I was trying with Code but it was not displaying properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you're grouping on `ID` as well as `Email`. Each row has a different value for `ID`, and hence a multiple rows for each email address (one for each ID).

I, however, always prefer a Cross Tab over the `PIVOT` operator. It's transferable between dialects, and it's less rigid:

```sql
SELECT Email,
       COUNT(CASE Department WHEN 'D1' THEN 1 END) AS D1,
       COUNT(CASE Department WHEN 'D2' THEN 1 END) AS D2,
       COUNT(CASE Department WHEN 'D3' THEN 1 END) AS D3,
       COUNT(CASE Department WHEN 'D4' THEN 1 END) AS D4
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
GROUP BY Email;
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the [ID] because it is unique.

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT [Email],[DepartmentName]
      FROM [dbo].[User]) U
      PIVOT (
      COUNT([DepartmentName]) 
      FOR [DepartmentName] IN( [D1],[D2],[D3],[D4])
  ) AS pivot_table;
```